# Google Sheet to Json Data Live Update Without Refresh Website Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, google-apps-script

this function runs fine.

What I am looking for

If someone updates data on google sheet without reloading webpage update DOM element help of any language.

I'm using the google sheet json file

`https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1XaFRnQfNPRP86UPNcdgQuCCH6AeVe5FZOxBHaIPZDpM/od6/public/values?alt=json`

```js
var myData = [];

// an example function that will get the data by index so it can be used however you want
function showDetails(index) {
   var selectedData = myData[index];
   alert(JSON.stringify(selectedData, null, 2));
}

$.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1XaFRnQfNPRP86UPNcdgQuCCH6AeVe5FZOxBHaIPZDpM/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) {

            myData = []; // reset whenever data loads
            var sheetData = data.feed.entry;

            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {

                var dataPoint = {
                  name: data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$slipno']['$t'],
                  id: data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$id']['$t'],
                  clientname: data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$clientname']['$t'],
                  delivery: data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$delivery']['$t']
                };
                myData.push(dataPoint); // add data point to array to reference later

                // var email = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$email']['$t'];
                // var delivery = data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$delivery']['$t'];

                document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML +=
                    ('<tr class="dd d-flex justify-content-around">' +
                        '<td>' +
                        " <span id='" + 't' + dataPoint.id + "'>" + dataPoint.name + '</span>' +
                        '<span class="cn" onclick="showDetails(' + i + ');">' + dataPoint.clientname + '</span>' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td class="ml-auto gg" onclick="showDetails(' + i + ');">' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>');
            }
        });
```

```css
tbody>tr>td>span {
                    text-align: left;
                    display: block;
                }
                
                .dd {
                    border-bottom: rgb(202, 202, 202) solid 1px;
                    display: block;
                }
                
                .cn {
                    font-weight: 700;
                }
                
                .gg::before {
                    content: ">";
                }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> brand</a>
            <ul class="navbar-nav  mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container text-center my-4">

        <!-- Table  -->
        <table class="table " id="testTable">
            <!-- Table head -->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Google Sheet Data</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Table head -->
        
            <!-- Table body -->
            <tbody id="demo">


            </tbody>
            <!-- Table body -->
        </table>
        <!-- Table  -->

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the `$.getJSON` function in a `setInterval` loop to poll the Google Sheets document for changes.

The below will check once a second for updates

```
setInterval(function () {$.getJSON(.....)}, 1000)
```

Comment: itis not working. if possible can you set this function in this code.

Comment: Could you provide more details than `not working`? What isn't working? What is the error message, etc

Comment: maybe is a syntax issue. I couldn't implement correctly, can you show an example in your answer.

Comment: you literally just replace `$.getJSON(.....)` with that giant `$.getJSON` above, and if it worked before, it'll work here, but just run every second rather than once

Comment: I appreciate your efforts maybe I did something wrong. it is continuously adding data section by section in DOM. can you add a right snippet in your answer. and happily end this conversation :)

Comment: Hi , @ManishS you need to empty your `demo` element first and then fill it with new data else it will get added again and again . i.e : Add this line outside your for loop `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML ="";` .Also , for syntax do like this : `setInterval(function () { $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1XaFRnQfNPRP86UPNcdgQuCCH6AeVe5FZOxBHaIPZDpM/od6/public/values?alt=json", function(data) { //your whole code here .. })} ,1000)`